# converting numeric arrays into list and savig in CSV in R

Tags: r, arrays, csv

I am trying to store two numerical arrays in an unusal form, e.g. c('[1;2;3]','[4;5;6]','[24;25;26]')

I need them in a CSV in single cells, like here

[image: final CSV]

So far I tried this:

```
DF
ID time Y
1  3    23
1  4    24
1  5    20 
2  2    12
2  8    15
3  2    19
3  3    23
3  5    21
3  6    32

timeList = list()
yList = list()
for (i in 1:3) {
  timeList[i] = DF$time
  yList[i] = DF$Y   
}

longTimeList = list(timeList)
longYList = list(yList)

DF <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
             P1 = longTimeList,
             P2 = longYList)
```

so the example DF woul read

```
 newDF <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
                 P1 = c('[3;4;5]','[2;8]','[2;3;5;6]'),
                 P2 = c('[23,24,20]','[12;15]','[19;23;21;32]'))
```

which should be stored in a CSV file to give something like that shown above.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, you ask an interesting question, with data and the code you're trying, your desired result, and you get some well considered answers. Your final challenge is to select the best answer for you by clicking on the check next to the answer you chose. This is completing the virtuous circle here as it marks this as an answered question that will be useful to others in the future. And welcome again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `aggregate` could help you

```
> aggregate(. ~ ID, DF, function(x) sprintf("[%s]", paste0(x, collapse = ";")))
  ID      time             Y
1  1   [3;4;5]    [23;24;20]
2  2     [2;8]       [12;15]
3  3 [2;3;5;6] [19;23;21;32]
```

Answer (score 2):

using **tidyverse**

```r
df <-
  structure(list(
    ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
    time = c(3L,
             4L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L),
    Y = c(23L, 24L, 20L, 12L, 15L,
          19L, 23L, 21L, 32L)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,
                -9L))

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~paste0(.x, collapse = ";"))) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(time, Y), ~paste0("[", .x, "]")))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      ID time      Y            
#>   <int> <chr>     <chr>        
#> 1     1 [3;4;5]   [23;24;20]   
#> 2     2 [2;8]     [12;15]      
#> 3     3 [2;3;5;6] [19;23;21;32]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

An option with `glue`

```
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), function(x)
      glue("[{str_c(x, collapse = ';')}]")))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     ID time      Y            
#  <int> <glue>    <glue>       
#1     1 [3;4;5]   [23;24;20]   
#2     2 [2;8]     [12;15]      
#3     3 [2;3;5;6] [19;23;21;32]
```